# AngularJS Expression Won't Evaluate in Value Field of Input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

What seems like a simple thing in AngularJS is not working for me and I was hoping you all could be of assistance. Specifically, I am trying to enter the result of an AngularJS expression in another input's "value" attribute. I have set the ng-model's and am calling those correctly, just can't figure out why it won't evaluate. I have tried doing the same expression below the input, and it evaluates, so I believe it's something to do with being in the value attribute which is causing the issue.The code I have currently is:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <label for="employeeID">Employee ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="employeeID" for="employeeID" placeholder="ANS1235482" ng-model="createNewUser.EmployeeId">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Johnathan" ng-model="createNewUser.FirstName">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Smith" ng-model="createNewUser.LastName">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="JohnathanSmith" value="createNewUser.LastName" >
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="***************">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <label>Role</label>
        <select class="input-block-level">
            <option value="user">User</option>
            <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, I would like to figure out how to get a username of the first letter of the first name and the full last name to auto-populate using data-binding, but at this point I haven't even been able to get just the standard first name + last name to work.

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="JohnathanSmith" ng-value="un" >
```

Use ng-change directive.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope){
  $scope.fn = "";
  $scope.ln = "";

  $scope.changed = function () {
    $scope.un = $scope.fn[0] + $scope.ln;
  };

}]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xuxogolifira/2/edit)**

Comment: Makes sense but still doesn't evaluate. Thank you though!

Comment: i am trying to create demo so give me few min.

Answer (score 1):

please use ng-value instead value

here demo: http://jsbin.com/zamih/1/edit

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <label for="employeeID">Employee ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="employeeID" for="employeeID" placeholder="ANS1235482" ng-model="createNewUser.EmployeeId">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Johnathan" ng-model="createNewUser.FirstName">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Smith" ng-model="createNewUser.LastName">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="JohnathanSmith" ng-value="createNewUser.LastName" >
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="***************">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <label>Role</label>
        <select class="input-block-level">
            <option value="user">User</option>
            <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That makes sense, sadly it's still not evaluating in my code.

Comment: Hm, so if that works as it is then I wonder why it's not working on my end =\ — Time to start taking things apart to look for the why

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
<div class="span4">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" class="input-block-level" 
         placeholder="JohnathanSmith" value="createNewUser.LastName" >
</div>
```

To this instead:

```
<div class="span4">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" class="input-block-level" 
         placeholder="JohnathanSmith" value="{{createNewUser.LastName}}" >
</div>
```

Your issue is that you are not evaluating `createNewUser.LastName` as an angular binding, but instead just assigning the text "createNewUser.LastName" to the `value` attribute. To fix this, put the `createNewUser.LastName` variable in double curly braces `{{...}}`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That makes perfect sense yet for some reason for me it's not evaluating as it seems it should be

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried any/all of these above mentioned methods and still not able to fix your problem, it could be that your updated files are not loaded to Chrome.
That's what happened to me.

There are two ways to make sure that your js files are up to date on the browser,

1) Hold shift while clicking the reload button of your browser

2) Hard reload your page

```
 * Open Developer Tools by either pressing F12 or ... -> More Tools -> Developer Tools
 * Right-click the reload button of your browser and click "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"
```